# Android Relative Layout on top other element

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I'm currently trying to make a data structure visualization app. The data structure I am trying to make is a stack.

I am struggling to make an element on top of another once the user presses "Push". Below is the code that makes an element go to the bottom of the screen.

I was wondering if are there any methods that could directly tells the next element to be aligned to the element that is already at the bottom now?

```
public void moveElem() {

    element1 = findViewById(R.id.element1);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams positionRules = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    positionRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    positionRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    element1.setLayoutParams(positionRules);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams sizeRules = element1.getLayoutParams();
    sizeRules.width = 400;
    sizeRules.height = 200;
    element1.setLayoutParams(sizeRules);
}
```

[image]

Thank you all so much!

Comment: update** I've tried this, but it directly overlays on top of the first element 
 positionRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, element1.getId());

Answer (score 0):

Use ALIGN_TOP and ALIGN_LEFT/ALIGN_RIGHT depends on what you need so it will make the next element the same alignment as the previous element and just add margins for the next element as well so it won't be exactly on top of the last one according the direction you need making it look like a stack.